# display & set default image with parameter passed in as URL

Tags: c#, xaml

How do I display an image & set an image if nothing is passed in @ '_imageURL', in a Silverlight 2.0 control? Assuming that i have an url passed in as a string (_imageURL) @ Page.xaml.cs, here is my snippet:

```
public Page(string _setLayout, string _imageURL, string _setTitleText, string _setDescriptionText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageURL))
        {
            //(image to display on load)
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageURL))
        {
            //image to display if no parameter passed in @ '_imageURL'
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `Image` declared in the xaml of the `Page`, like this:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage"/>
```

Then:

```
public Page(string _setLayout, string _imageURL, string _setTitleText, string _setDescriptionText)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageURL))
    {
        MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_imageURL));
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageURL))
    {
        MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Some\path\to\default\image.png"));
    }            
}
```

Comment: @ XAMeLi: Exactly. Did the same but it couldnt work. My bad. Actually the fault lies with the parameter syntax passed in from a SharePoint web part project. Thanks anyw! :)